# Function in lisp that displays a list in a specific way

Tags: list, lisp

I need to make a function in lisp that displays a list like this:

```
(a b (c d) (e f g) h) ->
(a
 b
 (c
  d)
 (e
  f 
  g)
 h)
```

So far i managed to make a function that displays a list like this.

```
(defun print1-lista(l)
   (princ pard)
   (do ((lst l (cdr lst)))
       ((null (cdr lst)) (princ (car lst)) (princ par))
     (princ (car lst))
     (terpri)))

   PRINT1-LISTA
   > (print1-lista '(1 (1 2) 3 4))
   {1
   (1 2)
   3
   4}
   }
```

Comment: You may want to reformat your question, it's tough to tell what you want exactly. Also, what lisp are you using?

Comment: I'm gonna reformat it immediately. I'm using xlisp-stat

Comment: You need to write a recursive function. Whenever the current element is a list, it has to call the function again with the contents. And the function needs to receive the indentation amount as a parameter.

Comment: @EmilBîc It's difficult to find any information about xlisp-stat from this century. I would recommend that you switch to a Common Lisp implementation, at least for learning. (There aren't that many xlisp users around to ask for help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Common Lisp, you can customize the printer in many ways.  For instance, the variables ***print-case*** and ***print-margin-right*** will control the case that symbols are printed in, and the right margin as used by the pretty printer.  Thus you can do something like this:

```
(let ((*print-case* :downcase)
      (*print-right-margin* 2))
  (pprint '(a b (c d) (e f g) h)))
```

to get output like this:

```
(a
 b
 (c
  d)
 (e
  f
  g)
 h)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty sketch of such a scheme for pretty printing in PLT-Scheme

```
(define (deep-ppr lst depth)
  (let ((elt (car lst)))
    (if (list? elt)
        (begin
          (printf "~a(~a\n" (make-string depth #\ ) (car elt))
          (deep-ppr (cdr elt) (+ 1 depth)))
        ;; not a list
        (begin
          (printf "~a~a" (make-string depth #\ ) elt)))
    (if (empty? (cdr lst)) (printf ")")
        (begin
          (printf "\n")
          (deep-ppr (cdr lst) depth)))))
```

Which yields this. You can change the scheme for introducing newlines however you'd like.

```
sicp.rkt> (deep-pp '(1 (1 2 4) 3 4 5 6 (1 2 3 5) 7) 0)

(1
 (1
  2
  4)
 3
 4
 5
 6
 (1
  2
  3
  5)
 7)
```

Comment: i am new to xlisp stat and still struggling to understand it so plt-scheme it's quite hard for me to understand

Comment: I posted a directly recursive version that might be easier for you to understand.

Comment: I wrote this for you specifically -- The least you can do is up & accept!

Comment: OP includes code like `(defun print1-lista(l)` so it appears the language needed here is Common Lisp, not Scheme.  It's hard to see why OP would accept an answer that won't run in that environment.